# Laravel 5 - NGINX Server Config Issue with URL Query Strings

Tags: nginx, routes, query-string, laravel-5

Laravel is not receiving any $_GET variables from the URL query string.  The $_GET and Input::all() are empty.

**Example:**

**example.app/ex/login.php?country=US**

The "country=US" never shows up in my $_GET variable

After much research and trying many different NGINX configurations, I can now only produce results when this example is used.

**Example:**

**example.app/index.php/ex/login.php?country=US**

The $_GET variable now shows the country name value pair.

What is the proper configuration to allow query strings within the URL?

My current sites-enabled configuration for my "example.app" is...

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.app;
root /home/vagrant/Code/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
   #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/registration.app-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

sendfile off;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the sites-enabled NGINX server configuration that ended up working for me...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name registration.app;
    root /home/vagrant/Code/registration/public;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/registration.app-error.log error;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    sendfile off;

    # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        #deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to just confirm that this is the actual answer to the problem. I'm experiencing the same issue. When I add "error_page 404 /index.php" to the config, it seems to work, but actually all the responses are 404 instead of the expected 200, and POST requests no longer work.

Comment: This solved a very irritating 404 issue for me thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

This appears correct, aside from being commented out.

```
location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

The bare bones one I use in testing is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/project/public;
    index index.php
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

$query_string and $args are functionally identical according to:
[NGINX Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html)

Comment: my try_files was: try_files $uri $uri/ =404;     ......    I just needed to replace the =404 with /index.php?$args; to tell nginx to treat these urls as query strings and not "give up" and display a 404 page because the files don't actually exist ....  This was to get CPVLabs working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Digital Ocean Droplet).    THANK YOU FOR AN INSTANT SOLUTION ... I <3 STACK OVERFLOW!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked only by changing 
            `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` to 
`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args` inside `location /` block on ubuntu (14.04) nginx

Answer (score 0):

My ***NGINX*** congfiguration was something like this:-

**From**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?is_args$args;
}
```

**To**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I just remove the ***is_args*** from ***try_files*** and working fine.