# Laravel 5/ 5.4 paginator is not working in NGINX production environement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-pagination

In my local environment i did `$items = Model::paginate(10);` and it worked. Then i pushed it to production and when i click on the pagination links it displays page 1 again and again. then i did `dd($items)`. i found that the `current Page` property of `length aware pagination` is not changing when i change the address to `/items?page=*`. How to make current page property change accordingly or there is some thing else? thanks in advance

Comment: So Laravel 5.3 or 5.4

Comment: laravel 5.4 it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using ubuntu 16.04 nginx server. The problem was that `$_GET` session variables were not being set properly. so what I did was inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and inside `location /` block/ directive I changed `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` and it worked. Or see [Laravel 5 - NGINX Server Config Issue with URL Query Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849149/laravel-5-nginx-server-config-issue-with-url-query-strings)

Comment: Wow, I have been searching for the cause of this for *far* too long.  This solves the issue perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me thank you, but please use code formatting tools next time.

Answer (score 0):

Awsome Thanks #Ahmed

I just had to change mine from

```
location / {    
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

to

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}
```

as i saw some of my other sites was using the @rewriteapp part and seem to work fine.

Comment: what is ``` @rewriteapp``` by the way??

Comment: @rewriteapp is just like a variable, it references the second location attribute in my example. it injects the 'rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;' part